# Server Apache TomEE at localhost failed to start

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, apache, tomcat

'Hi I am using Eclipse luna and Tomcat v7 on Mac OSX. My apache tomEE was running fine until I execute from the apache-tomee-webprofile-1.7.4 folder the startup.sh (previously i run the server only from eclipse). Then it stopped working and shows the following error "Server Apache TomEE at localhost failed to start." Also I tried to shutdown the server using the shutdown.sh but this is what it produces:

```
    ./shutdown.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/federicogiulianelli/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.4
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/federicogiulianelli/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.4
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/federicogiulianelli/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.4/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/federicogiulianelli/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.4/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/federicogiulianelli/Documents/Tomcat/apache-tomee-plus-1.7.4/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
objc[2185]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
giu 01, 2016 11:47:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
GRAVE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
giu 01, 2016 11:47:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
GRAVE: Catalina.stop: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:430)
```

I have tried deleting the .snap file and temp0 folder in the workspace folder. I have also tried to configure again tomEE. i referred to the question Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start and tried all solutions.But all this in vain. There is no other process running on port number 8080 but i don't know on the other port 
I use. In fact from the console of eclipse are wrote some errors like:

```
[...]
    giu 01, 2016 12:25:52 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
GRAVE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/siw-jee-es1]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet listener class: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2156)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:1843)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:360)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:971)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1227)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:176)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2153)
    ... 17 more
giu 01, 2016 12:25:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase removeChild
GRAVE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/siw-jee-es1]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1038)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1537)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1518)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1267)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1100)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[...]
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]][...]
giu 01, 2016 12:25:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
GRAVE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
```

I think that the problem is on the `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]` error but I don't know, can someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
```

`ConfigureListener` class is missing. Include [mojarra](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/) under webapp `/WEB-INF/lib` or Tomcat's `/lib`

Comment: I do what you suggest but ,even if i don't have that error anymore, Tomcat doesn't start anyway...